# How to use Grouped Use statements with Symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony, php-7.1

I have PHP 7.1 installed on my machine and I'm developping an application with Symfony. When I tried to group my use statements from same namespace I got an error, saying that they were never declared.

My `use`:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\{
    Route, Method
};
```

The error shown int the browser:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Route" in method AppBundle\Controller\EpisodiosController::listarAction() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in /home/vinicius/Documentos/controle-de-series/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/home/vinicius/Documentos/controle-de-series/app/config/routing.yml").
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the error is a bug concerning to the annotations, and not to the hole framework. So, splitting the use statements of the annotations worked just fine.